# I can't manage to get total number of pages for list

Tags: java

That's my code so far if someone can help me there, I need to calculate the total number of pages as well, but I can't manage it...

```
package assignment2;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class Book {
    private String title;
    //Private class fields
    private int numOfPages;
    public String getTitle() {
        //Getter
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        //Setter
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getNumOfPages() {
        return numOfPages;
    }

    public void setNumOfPages(int numOfPages) {
        this.numOfPages = numOfPages;
    }

    public Book(String title, int pages) {
        //A parameterized constructor with two parameters
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setNumOfPages(numOfPages);
    }

    public static class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Book> books = new LinkedList<>();
            books.add(new Book("The Catcher in the Rye", 190));
            //List of Book instances
            books.add(new Book("Song of Myself", 259));
            books.add(new Book("A Man Called Ove", 295));
            books.add(new Book("Lolita", 360));
            books.add(new Book("The Diary of a Young Girl", 352));
            books.add(new Book("The Tattooist of Auschwitz", 288));
            books.add(new Book("The Notebook", 214));
            List<Book> temporaryBook = new ArrayList<>(books);
            //Sublist that stops main method
            BookApp bkapp = new BookApp();
            int totalPages = bkapp.calcTotalPages(temporaryBook, 0);
            out.printf("Total number of books: %d\n", books.size());
            out.printf("Total pages: %d\n", totalPages);
        }
    }

    //End of Main class
    public static class BookApp {
        public int calcTotalPages(List<Book> bookList, int accum) {
            if (bookList.size() == 0)
                return accum;
            return calcTotalPages(bookList, accum + bookList.remove(0).getNumOfPages());
        }
    }

    //End of class BookApp
}
```

Comment: Why you use a recursive call? Is it necessary there?

Comment: It is not necessary, I just found it easier, but obviously is not working :(

Comment: Also, you need not `import java.lang.System` this is automatically imported behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `calcTotalPages` as follows:

```
public static int calcTotalPages(List<Book> bookList) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Book book : bookList) {
        sum += book.getNumOfPages();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Or using `Stream` API as follows:

```
public static int calcTotalPages(List<Book> bookList) {
    return bookList.stream().mapToInt(Book::getNumOfPages).sum();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class Book {
    private String title;
    private int numOfPages;

    public Book(String title, int numOfPages) {
        this.title = title;
        this.numOfPages = numOfPages;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getNumOfPages() {
        return numOfPages;
    }
}

public class BookApp {
    public static class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Book> books = new LinkedList<>();
            books.add(new Book("The Catcher in the Rye", 190));
            books.add(new Book("Song of Myself", 259));
            books.add(new Book("A Man Called Ove", 295));
            books.add(new Book("Lolita", 360));
            books.add(new Book("The Diary of a Young Girl", 352));
            books.add(new Book("The Tattooist of Auschwitz", 288));
            books.add(new Book("The Notebook", 214));

            int totalPages = calcTotalPages(books);
            System.out.printf("Total number of books: %d\n", books.size());
            System.out.printf("Total pages: %d\n", totalPages);
        }
    }

    public static int calcTotalPages(List<Book> bookList) {
        return bookList.size() == 0 ? 0 : bookList.stream().mapToInt(Book::getNumOfPages).sum();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Total number of books: 7
Total pages: 1958
```

Comment: This is the best explanation, which also address compile issues. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, @Bradley for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Since the recursive call is not necessary you can simplify that with:

```
public int calculateTotalPages(List<Book> books) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (Book book : books) {
        counter += book.getNumOfPages();
    }
    return counter;
}
```

If you are familiar with Java 8 streams you can proceed with:

```
public int calculateTotalPages(List<Book> books) {
    return books.stream()
            .mapToInt(Book::getNumOfPages)
            .sum();
}
```

There are some things that can be improved in code:

- function name `calcTotalPages` -> `calculateTotalPages`
- name of argument `bookList` -> `books`

Answer (score -1):

I took the liberty of removing the inner class and just sticking with a simple stream to calculate the total pages as the ones before me did. Take a look at the main method:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Book> books = new LinkedList<>();
        books.add(new Book("The Catcher in the Rye", 190)); // List of Book instances
        books.add(new Book("Song of Myself", 259));
        books.add(new Book("A Man Called Ove", 295));
        books.add(new Book("Lolita", 360));
        books.add(new Book("The Diary of a Young Girl", 352));
        books.add(new Book("The Tattooist of Auschwitz", 288));
        books.add(new Book("The Notebook", 214));

        int totalPages = books.stream().mapToInt(b -> b.getNumOfPages()).sum();
        System.out.printf("Total number of books: %d\n", books.size());
        System.out.printf("Total pages: %d\n", totalPages);

        // for fun:
        books.stream().forEach(b -> System.out.printf("Current book: %1s, \n Current number of pages: %2d \n\n",
                b.getTitle(), b.getNumOfPages())); // prints out each book and how many pages it has
    }
```

I also changed your Book constructor to:

```
    public Book(String title, int numOfPages) { // A parameterized constructor with two parameters
    this.title = title;
    this.numOfPages = numOfPages;
}
```

I think it's clearer what you wanna do with this constructor, but it's a matter of opinion.

The whole code:

```
package app;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Book {
private String title; // Private class fields
private int numOfPages;

public String getTitle() { // Getter
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) { // Setter
    this.title = title;
}

public int getNumOfPages() {
    return numOfPages;
}

public void setNumOfPages(int numOfPages) {
    this.numOfPages = numOfPages;
}

public Book(String title, int numOfPages) { // A parameterized constructor with two parameters
    this.title = title;
    this.numOfPages = numOfPages;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + this.numOfPages;
}

public static class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Book> books = new LinkedList<>();
        books.add(new Book("The Catcher in the Rye", 190)); // List of Book instances
        books.add(new Book("Song of Myself", 259));
        books.add(new Book("A Man Called Ove", 295));
        books.add(new Book("Lolita", 360));
        books.add(new Book("The Diary of a Young Girl", 352));
        books.add(new Book("The Tattooist of Auschwitz", 288));
        books.add(new Book("The Notebook", 214));

        int totalPages = books.stream().mapToInt(b -> b.getNumOfPages()).sum();
        System.out.printf("Total number of books: %d\n", books.size());
        System.out.printf("Total pages: %d\n", totalPages);

        // for fun:
        books.stream().forEach(b -> System.out.printf("Current book: %1s, \n Current number of pages: %2d \n\n",
                b.getTitle(), b.getNumOfPages()));
    }
}

}
```